# search capability to the listview using textbox

Tags: c#

I was trying to create a search function on my listview using textbox, but whenever I click the button to search, I got a strange error: " "Cannot add or insert the item '1' in more than one place. You must first remove it from its current location or clone it. Parameter name: item ". I hope you can help me.
Here's the code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        string command = "server = localhost; port = 3306; Username = root; Database = listview";
        string connect = "Select * from listview.users where Username LIKE '%%" + textBox1.Text + "%%'";
        Con = new MySqlConnection(command);
        Cmd = new MySqlCommand(connect, Con);

        listView1.Items.Clear();

        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem lvitem = new ListViewItem(Reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                for (int i = 1; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    lvitem.SubItems.Add(Reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
                    listView1.Items.Add(lvitem);
                    count++;
                }

                MessageBox.Show(this, "There are " + count + "item(s) found.");
                Con.Close();
                Con.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its due to adding lvitem more than once. Is it a listview with one column?

Comment: Also, is this WPF or WinForm?

Comment: check my answer and tell me if helped you,.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should start from 0.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
{
     ....
}
```

Also your first string should be called-> `connectionString` not `command`. Second string should be `query` not `connection`. This is not a big problem but it is confusing.

Also if you are using try/catch when you are using connection, you should Close the connection in finally block, because if exception occur `Con.Close()` will be not hit. You don't need to call `Con.Dispose()` if you are calling `Con.Close()`.

```
try
{
    Con.Open();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //do something with exception.
}
finally
{
    Con.Close();
}
```

Other tip don't use global Connection, Command and so on. Connection pooling is your friend. You can search in the web what is connection pooling. Also by convection it will be nice Con and Cmd to start with lower case.